# Pandasのgroupbyがうまく機能していないので教えていただきたいです。

Tags: python, pandas

## 問題

以下のようなデータフレームがあります。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

都道府県名(47都道府県)と市区町村名(618種類)、面積がカラムになっております。

このDataFrameに対して、

都道府県名が`北海道`の行に対して、市区町村ごとに面積の平均を求めたいです。

そこで以下のようなコードを実行したところ

```
# 都道府県ごとに面積当たりの価格の平均が高いところを調べたい
df[df["都道府県名"]=="北海道"].groupby('市区町村名').mean()
```

以下のような結果が出力されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

北海道だけ抽出したのにも関わらず、なぜかほかの県の市区町村が残っており、平均値が計算されています。

この現象の原因がわからずこまっています。
わかる方ぜひとも教えてください。

追記
SwarmPlotを試してみても以下のようにxが各都道府県になってしまいます。
都道府県名には北海道のみなのですが、なぜでしょうか

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

追記2
北海道に対応する市区町村名の数を数えたところ、やはり正しいようです。
そして、categoryという欄になぜかすべての市区町村名が載っています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: まずは `df[df["都道府県名"]=="北海道"]` を実行して北海道地区だけが抽出されているかどうかを確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: 北海道だけが抽出されております。

Comment: そうなりますと、例えば「北海道」に対して全ての市区町村名(600種類)の組み合わせがデータフレームの中に存在しているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: こちらも確認しましたが、18種類のみでした。

Comment: 「市区町村名」カラムが category 型になっているので、category 型にする理由が特に無ければ object 型に戻せば良いかと思います。`df['市区町村名'] = df['市区町村名'].astype('object')`

Comment: category 型にしておく理由がある場合は [Pandas groupby with categories with redundant nan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48471648/pandas-groupby-with-categories-with-redundant-nan) の回答を参照してください。

Comment: 解決できました！カテゴリの時のやり方まで教えていただきましてとてもありがたいです。ベストアンサーにさせていただきたいので、回答のほうにいただければと思います。

Comment: https://teratail.com/questions/342165　とのマルチポストでしょうか？あちらの方にも解決までの方法を記述された方が良いでしょう。

Comment: @JinWatanabe 回答に書きましたが、内容的には単なるコピペなのでベストアンサーは元記事の Michael Dorner に付けるべきでしょうね。。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

コメントにも書きましたが、以下の承認された回答にある通りです。

[Pandas groupby with categories with redundant nan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50579578)

> Since Pandas 0.23.0, the groupby method can now take a parameter observed which fixes this issue if it is set to True (False by default). Below is the exact same code as in the question with just **observed=True** added:

[pandas.DataFrame.groupby — pandas 1.2.4 documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

> **observed: bool, default False**
>
> This only applies if any of the groupers are Categoricals. If True: only show observed values for categorical groupers. **If False: show all values for categorical groupers**.